# Need to create a formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, picklist

I need to create a formula field which returns the date when the status (picklist) field is marked as complete.

I have tried below formula but it is updating today's date for all the ones which were updated long back. Could you suggest what changes need to be made?

```
If(
    Ispickval(status__c, 'completed'), 
    TODAY(), 
    NULL
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [Edit] your question to include that information, otherwise this comes off as a "do my work for me" request.

Comment: I have added the formula

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adjusting the formula to be syntactically correct, and have retracted my close vote.

Comment: Have you checked Field History tracking option?

Comment: No, can you tell what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Formula fields are re-calculated every time that the record is accessed. They're not a one-time calculation, so they are not suited for the problem you're trying to solve here.

Instead, you should use a before-save record-triggered flow with a custom date field to:

- detect when your record's status is changing to "completed"
- and then execute an immediate action to set your date field with `TODAY()`